# convert bitmap to integer array form and then compress it in android

Tags: android

how does bitmap return data in the form of integer array. And how do i convert it into integer array form. After conversion to integer array form i want to compress that integer array form. Is it possible? If so how?
Kindly help me out

Comment: What is your main purpose? You want to compress a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the integer array, Bitmap class already have [`compress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method. May be it already fits your needs.

Comment: yes i want to reduce the integer array size allocation and by that way i want to compress the bitmap. I have used bitmap.compress . but will it actually compress( i mean will it reduce pixels)